# What is collection/Pair error in cypher script?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-shell

I have written a buggy cypher script, but I cannot find the actual problem.

##### Here is the crucial part of the script:

```
:begin
:param measured => 'heat';
:param vals => [
    {d: datetime({year: 2022, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 4}), v: 47980},
    {d: datetime({year: 2022, month: 2, day: 1, hour: 4}), v: 50840},
    {d: datetime({year: 2022, month: 3, day: 1, hour: 4}), v: 53190}];
MATCH (i:Installation:HeatPump {name: "Demoanlage"})--(m:MeasurementSite {measuredObj: $measured})--(me:Meter)
    WHERE ID(i) = $hpId WITH me UNWIND $vals as val
        MERGE (me)-[:MEASURED_MANUALLY {createdAt: datetime.transaction()}]->
            (v:Val {d: val.d, v: val.v}) RETURN v;
:commit
```

###### There is one more `:begin :commit` block, this might also be a problem.

##### When I run this script I am getting the following output:

```
// using a cypher shell 
sdptest@neo4j> :source /home/myname/path/to/cypher-scripts/data_imports/add_demo_hp_vals.cypher;
org/neo4j/internal/helpers/collection/Pair // this is in red, kind of error message
sdptest@neo4j# // note the hash instead of the 'greater than' sign
```

For making the question clearer: I don't get the `org/neo4j/internal/helpers/collection/Pair` *'error'* and I don't get why the hash suddenly shows up (which looks like a root user in a usual linux shell)?

Googling did not help.

(Version: *Neo4j 4.4.9*, *cypher-shell* the same).

##### Edit

May it is not allowed to add parameter in scripted transaction (`:begin :commit`)? Because the query seems to be OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a shot in the dark, but I think you are missing a parameter, `$hpId`, in the following snippet:

```
:begin
:param measured => 'heat';
:param vals => [
    {d: datetime({year: 2022, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 4}), v: 47980},
    {d: datetime({year: 2022, month: 2, day: 1, hour: 4}), v: 50840},
    {d: datetime({year: 2022, month: 3, day: 1, hour: 4}), v: 53190}];
MATCH (i:Installation:HeatPump {name: "Demoanlage"})--(m:MeasurementSite {measuredObj: $measured})--(me:Meter)
    WHERE ID(i) = $hpId WITH me UNWIND $vals as val
        MERGE (me)-[:MEASURED_MANUALLY {createdAt: datetime.transaction()}]->
            (v:Val {d: val.d, v: val.v}) RETURN v;
:commit
```

Try after, providing it a value.

Comment: This is a good guess, but a missing parameter would produce a different error message (and way more clear one).

Comment: I hope so, yes.

Comment: In this case it would look like: `An error occurred while in an open transaction. The transaction will be rolled back and terminated. Error: Expected parameter(s): hpId`.

Comment: Cool got it, thanks. Then it's trying to convey something else

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way of executing your script via cypher-shell.  Save it into a file then running the contents of that file thru cypher-shell command.

From bash terminal; 1) create the file (vi file) 2) copy/paste/save your code 3) then run below command thru bash command.  It will pass the contents of file and give it to cypher-shell to execute.

```
 cat file | cypher-shell -u neo4j -p <neo4j_password> --format plain
```